# keep holding a key and release a other

Tags: python, pygame

i'm actually creating my first game with pygame, but i encounter an issue :
When i'm holding 2 button, everything work perfectly , but as soon as i release one of them , pygame.event.get() return a empty list even if i keep holding the other one.
Because of that issue , my character can't jump forward.
thx for help !

Using python Windows 10 and pygame 1.9.6

## in the "character" class :

```
def move_right(self):
    self.speedx += 3
    self.sprite = "stand_r"
def move_left(self):
    self.speedx -= 3
    self.sprite = "stand_l"
def speed_effect(self):
    self.posx += self.speedx
    self.posy -= self.speedy
    #speed limitation :
    if self.speedx > 10 :
        self.speedx = 10
    if self.speedx < -10 :
        self.speedx = -10
```

## before main loop :

```
pygame.key.set_repeat(100,30)
pygame.time.Clock().tick(30)
```

## in the main loop :

```
for event in pygame.event.get():  
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if event.type == QUIT:
        continuer = 0
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if keys[pygame.K_d] or event.key == K_d:
            character.move_right()
        if keys[pygame.K_a] or event.key == K_a:
            character.move_left()
        #jump
        if character.grounded :
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                character.speedy = 30
```

pygame.event.get() return a empty list after releasing one button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event loop is only executed, when an event occurs. An event occurs at the moment when a button is pressed and a 2nd time when the button is released. When the button is hold no event happens, and the event loop is not executed.
The movement of the mouse would be an event which causes the event loop to be executed.

Use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) in the main loop (outside the event loop), to get the state of the keys at any time and to perform the movement of the `character`. The states which are given by `pygame.key.get_pressed()` are synchronized when `pygame.event.get()` is called.

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():  
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if event.type == QUIT:
        continuer = 0
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if character.grounded :
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                character.speedy = 30

keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_d]:
    character.move_right()
if keys[pygame.K_a]:
    character.move_left()
```